# How to wrap a number of pandas operations into a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a tedious task and I want to automate a little bit of it since many steps are always the same. I do some cleaning and rearranging fo data and the final output is a excel file.

I have put into a function put I get the error "No objects to concatenate". Any ideas why this is the case? When I try the lines one by one outside of the function everthing works fine. I just want to enter the city name like London into the function `clean_data_output_excel(cityname)` and it should do everything.

```
def clean_data_output_excel(cityname):
    path = r'C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\Cities\cityname'
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
    cityname = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files))
    cityname = cityname.drop(['UpTo'], axis=1)
    cityname['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(cityname['Time'], dayfirst=True)
    cityname = cityname.rename(columns = {'Time': 'Date'})
    cityname = cityname.set_index('Date')
    cityname = cityname.sort_values(by='Date')
    cityname.to_excel('Output/cityname_dailydata.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised by `pd.concat` because `all_files` is empty:

```
>>> pd.concat([])
...
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Try to use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to evaluate `cityname` in your path:

```
def clean_data_output_excel(cityname):
    # Use f-strings here
    path = fr'C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\Cities\{cityname}'
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
    # Don't use cityname as your dataframe variable
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files))
    df = df.drop(['UpTo'], axis=1)
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], dayfirst=True)
    df = df.rename(columns = {'Time': 'Date'})
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
    # Use f-strings here too
    df.to_excel(f'Output/{cityname}_dailydata.xlsx')
```

Comment: Do you know how I can also get the last line to output the correct name? Currently it does output a file named "cityname_dailydata.xlsx" instead of london_dailydate for example.

Comment: It says no such file or directory. As a single line of code it works.

Comment: Are you sure Output directory exists?

Comment: Yes, it is there and when I use the lines seperate it works and writes the file in that directory. When I don't change it it writes cityname_dailydate.xlsx in that directory.

Comment: Don't use `cityname` as variable name for your dataframe else your override the name of the city. I rewrote your code. Can you check it again, please?